# Exception caught by Gesture

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using an email auth package to verify the OTP via email. When I click on "Send OTP" button debug console only shows "true" but If the Send OTP button clicks then it must also print => 'otp sent' or 'otp not sent' as mentioned in the sendOTP() function .

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:email_auth/email_auth.dart';

void main() => runApp(
  MaterialApp(home: HomePage(),
  theme: ThemeData.dark(),
  ),
);
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
   final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _otpController = TextEditingController();

  void sendOTP()async{
    EmailAuth.sessionName = "Temp name";
    var res = await (EmailAuth.sendOtp(recieverMail: _emailController.text));
    if(res) print('otp sent');
    else print('otp not sent');
  }

  void validateOTP(){
    var res = EmailAuth.validate(recieverMail: _emailController.text, userOTP: _otpController.text);
    if(res) {
    print('otp verified');
    }
    else {
      print('wrong otp');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: _emailController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
              ),
          ),
          TextField(
              controller: _otpController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Enter otp",
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              obscureText: true,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () => sendOTP(),
            child: Text('Send OTP'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => validateOTP(),
            child: Text('Verify OTP'),
          ),
          ],
        ),
      )
      );
  }
}
```

**And the debug console throw an error when I tap on validate OTP button:**

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length
```

**When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:**
[image: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack]

Comment: Hi @JayantSharma, is your issue resolved ? IF not kindly raise a issue in the repo, I will take it forward from there.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and it is working fine.

I've placed my name for the **sessionName** value, and completed my email address in the first field input (it is quite hidden with the dark mode actually), and then tapped "Send OTP" button, and it worked.

First it printed:
`I/flutter ( 5409): true`

And after a couple seconds: `I/flutter ( 5409): otp sent`

I've checked on my email address and received an email with the OTP number.

Then I pasted it into the Enter otp field, tapped Verify OTP and the console printed

`I/flutter ( 5409): Validation success`

`I/flutter ( 5409): otp verified`

The exceptions you are receiving are because of the implementation of [email](https://pub.dev/packages/email_auth). If you check at their code, the ***validate*** method is asking for the length of a variable called **_finalEmail**, but _finalEmail is set only if **sendOtp** was called first, so if you tap it in the wrong order you get the '**length**' exception:

```
import 'dart:async';
// import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

class EmailAuth {
  // static const MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel('email_auth');
  // static Future<String> get platformVersion async {
  //   final String version = await _channel.invokeMethod('getPlatformVersion');
  //   return version;
  // }

  static String sessionName;
  static String _finalOTP;
  static String _finalEmail;

  static bool _isEmail(String email) {
    String p =
        r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+";
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(p);
    print(regExp.hasMatch(email));
    return regExp.hasMatch(email);
  }

  static Future<bool> sendOtp({String recieverMail}) async {
    try {
      if (!_isEmail(recieverMail)) {
        print("email ID is not valid");
        return false;
      }
      http.Response _response = await http.get(
          "https://app-authenticator.herokuapp.com/auth/${recieverMail.toLowerCase()}?CompanyName=$sessionName");
      Map<String, dynamic> _data = convert.jsonDecode(_response.body);
      if (_data["success"]) {
        _finalEmail = recieverMail;
        _finalOTP = _data["OTP"].toString();
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
      return false;
    }
  }

  static bool validate({String recieverMail, String userOTP}) {
    if (_finalEmail.length > 0 && _finalOTP.length > 0) {
      if (recieverMail.trim() == _finalEmail.trim() &&
          userOTP.trim() == _finalOTP.trim()) {
        print("Validation success");
        return true;
      } else {
        print("Validation Falied");
        return false;
      }
    }
    print("Missing Data");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added my email address first then click on "Send OTP" button. I received only 'true', I haven't receive 'otp sent' in the console.

Comment: Thats weird. The email address is real? I mean, it's not a test email address? If so, I think there's maybe some firewall issue, or the server blocking your request for some reason.

Comment: No, I am using my personal email i.e a real email and I have checked the spam folder too. Main issue is I haven't get the 'otp sent' message in the console.